# Insert not working using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have existing system from my new employer it was built with codeigniter,
Now I want to modify the registration/insert function.

On existing I have database

***Client Details(tblprojects)***

`name,status,descriptions,gender,age` and more

Now on this registration I want to add another fields will save to another table to within this registration field

I add

***Tenant Details(tblprojectstenant)***

```
tenantid,ownername,dewa,email,buildingname,rent,size and more....
```

then to do this i create another model for tenant since my existing registration field are working.

**Tenant Model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Ptenant_model extends CRM_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //insert into user table
    public function add($data)
    {
       $tenant =$this->db->insert('tblprojectstenant', $data);
    }



}
?>
```

View (registration)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<?php echo render_input('estimated_hours','estimated_hours',isset($client) ? $client->status : '','text'); ?>
                        </div>



 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <?php $value = (isset($tenant) ? $tenant->name : ''); ?>
 <?php echo render_input('name','TenantName',$value); ?>
 </div>
```

Then the only data sent from registration is only for client, but on my tenant it's not working.

**I know the php a little bit , I read about codeigniter I think I follow the tutorials but its not working.
** hope anyone can help me thankyou!

Comment: are you using <form> tag in your view to pass data to controller?

Comment: simply use <input> tag for your table data

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to show where Ptenant_model->add() is getting called.

Comment: Yes, there is too much code missing to be able to answer.